# Setting Width and Height of Flash AS3 Slider Component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to set a custom skin using the built-in AS3 slider component in Flash CS4. I have the following code, but setting `myslider.width` and `myslider.height` does not seem to have any effect. The slider is still displayed at the default width and height, and my custom sliderTrackSkin is being scaled down.

```
import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.controls.SliderDirection;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

var myslider:Slider = new Slider();
myslider.direction = SliderDirection.VERTICAL;
myslider.width = 43;
myslider.height = 110;
myslider.minimum = 1;
myslider.maximum = 90;
myslider.value = 30;
myslider.snapInterval = 1;
myslider.liveDragging = true;
myslider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, slider_change);
myslider.move(640, 60);
myslider.setStyle("thumbUpSkin", thumb1);
myslider.setStyle("thumbDownSkin", thumb1);
myslider.setStyle("thumbOverSkin", thumb1);
myslider.setStyle("sliderTrackSkin", slidertrack1);
addChild(myslider);
```

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `myslider.width` and `myslider.height` were taking effect on the parent, but the thumb and track of the slider component were not being resized. I had to manually resize the thumb and track like this:

```
var mysliderthumb = Sprite(myslider.getChildAt(1));
mysliderthumb.height = 34;
mysliderthumb.width = 15;

var myslidertrack = Sprite(myslider.getChildAt(0));
myslidertrack.height = 15;
myslidertrack.width = 100;
```

Furthermore because I had `myslider.direction = SliderDirection.VERTICAL`, the thumb and track were being rotated 90 degrees so I had to flip the width and height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `myslider.validateNow()` method after all properties are set and skin is applied.

Comment: Thanks but that was not the issue. I figured it out, though.